# How do we handle this kind of series of series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Let $S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$, what is the value of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{S(i)}$ ?

The expression of $S(n)$ is obvious.
The calculus of something like $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1/k^2$ involves some classical Fourier series.
I was wondering if we could come up with useful ideas in order to solve the question on the first line. Stuck. Any hint ?

Comment: *Hint*: partial fraction decomposition $\frac1{n(n+1)(2n+1)}=\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}-\frac4{2n+1}$.

Comment: Many thanks ! I understand how to do this now.